# scrolling linear frames

Tags: android, scroll, android-linearlayout

I m developing interface containing 2 linear frame. And I want to activate vertical scrolling for each frame.

How to do it ?

Are there an attribute in the linear layout xml definition to add in order to activate scrolling ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ScrollView** instead of **LinearLayout** for Scrolling purpose.

[ScrollView Example.](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)